# hessian matrix of a keras model with tf.hessians

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, hessian-matrix

I want to compute the Hessian matrix of a keras model w.r.t. its input in graph mode using `tf.hessians`.
Here is a minimal example

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.Input((10,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(1)
])
model.summary()

@tf.function
def get_grads(inputs):
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(model(inputs))
    return tf.gradients(loss, inputs)

@tf.function
def get_hessian(inputs):
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(model(inputs))
    return tf.hessians(loss, inputs)

batch_size = 3
test_input = tf.random.uniform((batch_size, 10))
out = model(test_input) # works fine
grads = get_grads(test_input) # works fine
hessian = get_hessian(test_input) # raises ValueError: None values not supported.
```

While the forward pass and the `get_grads` function work fine, the `get_hessian` function raises the `ValueError: None values not supported.`.

In this example

```py
@tf.function
def get_hessian_(inputs):
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(inputs**2)
    return tf.hessians(loss, inputs)

get_hessian_(tf.random.uniform((3,)))[0]
# <tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
# array([[2., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 2., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 2.]], dtype=float32)>
```

`tf.hessians` yields the expected result without error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code example,

you are trying to get hessian of `f(x)`(model outputs) w.r.t. `x`(inputs) and `f` is linear (the model is linear).

Hessian of `f(x)` w.r.t. `x` should actually be a zero tensor, but `tf.hessians` can't handle that properly, resulting the error. Adding an additional layer with non-linear activation will eliminate the error.

Codes examples:

Using `tf.hessians` to get hessian:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    Dense(10,activation='sigmoid'), #remove this line and you will get error
    Dense(1)
])
@tf.function
def get_hessian(inputs):
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(model(inputs))
    return tf.hessians(loss, inputs)

batch_size = 3
tf.random.set_seed(123)
test_input = tf.random.uniform((3,10),minval=1.5,maxval=2.5)
hessian = get_hessian(test_input)
print(type(hessian))
print(len(hessian))
print(hessian[0].shape)
print(hessian[0][0,0,0,0])
print(hessian[0][0,0,0,1])
'''
<class 'list'>
1
(3, 10, 3, 10)
tf.Tensor(0.0028595054, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(0.0009458237, shape=(), dtype=float32)
'''
```

Using `tf.GradientTape()` to get hessian:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    Dense(10,activation='sigmoid'), #remove this line and get_hessian return None
    Dense(1)
])
@tf.function
def get_hessian(inputs):
    with tf.GradientTape() as t2:
      t2.watch(inputs)
      with tf.GradientTape() as t1:
        t1.watch(inputs)
        loss = tf.reduce_sum(model(inputs))
      g=t1.gradient(loss,inputs)
    return t2.jacobian(g,inputs)

batch_size = 3
tf.random.set_seed(123)
test_input = tf.random.uniform((3,10),minval=1.5,maxval=2.5)
hessian = get_hessian(test_input)
print(type(hessian))
print(hessian.shape if hessian is not None else None)
print(hessian[0,0,0,0] if hessian is not None else None)
print(hessian[0,0,0,1] if hessian is not None else None)
'''
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>
(3, 10, 3, 10)
tf.Tensor(0.0028595058, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(0.0009458238, shape=(), dtype=float32)
'''
```

In case you want to get a zero tensor, you can use `unconnected_gradients=tf.UnconnectedGradients.ZERO`

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    Dense(1)
])
@tf.function
def get_hessian(inputs):
    with tf.GradientTape() as t2:
      t2.watch(inputs)
      with tf.GradientTape() as t1:
        t1.watch(inputs)
        loss = tf.reduce_sum(model(inputs))
      g=t1.gradient(loss,inputs,unconnected_gradients=tf.UnconnectedGradients.ZERO)
    return t2.jacobian(g,inputs,unconnected_gradients=tf.UnconnectedGradients.ZERO)

batch_size = 3
tf.random.set_seed(123)
test_input = tf.random.uniform((3,10),minval=1.5,maxval=2.5)
hessian = get_hessian(test_input)
print(type(hessian))
print(hessian.shape)
print(tf.math.count_nonzero(hessian))
'''
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>
(3, 10, 3, 10)
tf.Tensor(0, shape=(), dtype=int64)
'''
```

Comment: [`tf.hessians`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/hessians) says it returns * A list of Hessian matrices of `sum(ys)` for each `x` in `xs`.* I find that a little obscure. In your example the output is shape `(10, 4, 10, 4)`. Can you explain further how I index the second partial derivative of `f` with respect to inputs `xi` and `xj`?